# Using the google appengine maven plugin to deploy a Jax-RS war

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, jax-rs, web-deployment, web-inf

I'm trying to make a simple base project to deploy a service I make using Jax-RS librarys to my Google app engine cloud space. The problem is that I don't know how to configure the plugin properly to not keep looking to a webapp directory under the target folder. The structure of the Jax-rs project puts the web.xml and all other WEB-INF files under the resources directory instead of a webapp directory. Is there a way to configure the maven plugin to deploy my already built and zipped up war file?

This is the error I see

> [INFO] Updating Google App Engine Application Unable to find the
>   webapp directory C:\dev\gameTrunk\server\target\HOMMTG-server-1.0
>   usage: AppCfg [options]  [] []
>
> Action must be one of:   help: Print help for a specific action.
>   download_app: Download a previously uploaded app version.
>   request_logs: Write request logs in Apache common log format.
>   rollback: Rollback an in-progress update.   start: Start the specified
>   server version.

and it goes on with all the appengine plugin targets...

This s my pom

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                <webResources>
                    <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Thats just the plugins part but its almost exactly the same as the guestbook example project except for the path for the WEB-INF directory

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to configure the appengine-maven-plugin to use a different directory for the war contents.  It would be best though to probably create a multimodule build where one submodule just used the maven-ant-plugin to assemble the war directory and then run the plugin on that instead.  I don't think we want to make that configurable in the plugin, since it doesn't really align with the maven-war-plugin, and configuring that would make it difficult to setup your project to use the maven-war-plugin seamlessly in the future.

The configuration you currently have for the war-plugin in your pom isn't necessary unless you want interpolation of the version number into the appengine-web.xml.  I'm happy to help with setting up your pom so that the official Google App Engine Maven plugin works correctly for you.

Comment: I do't have my pom file on this machine to give you but the gist of my project is that I am building a war with jax-rs libraries that uses the standard resource directory to hold all the INF directories. The output of a different project is that war file. I have a separate project just for uploading to app engine. But it doesn't seem to be configurable to just use the war I provide. If you can think of a way to do this with a zipped war file, I'd be interested but if its not possible I'll just explode it as part of the build. My issue then becomes, what does the app engine plugin need exposed?

Comment: You'll need to explode it for now.  Sounds like we could work a bit on this though, let me think through it.  I see a few issues logged on the project to make this experience better.  I'm bogged down on a few other projects at the moment, but let me see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

(The instructions below apply to [maven-gae-plugin](http://www.kindleit.net/maven_gae_plugin/), not appengine-maven-plugin. 
Have I told you how much Google sucks in Open Source today?)

I think you must add in your maven-gae-plugin a property called `appDir` pointing to your webapp directory, like this:

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <appDir>PATH-TO-YOUR-BUILT-EXPLODED-WAR-PATH</appDir>
        </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

However, I must stress that changing the path in Maven produces undesirable results (you're mixing source and object code, your .ignore files will get messed up, and other weird things)

Note you STILL NEED your unpacked war somewhere. One way to achieve that is to create another .war project and use dependencies-unpack into it. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html

(reference: https://github.com/maven-gae-plugin/maven-gae-plugin/blob/master/maven-gae-plugin/src/main/java/net/kindleit/gae/EngineGoalBase.java)

(just in case, there is a JAX-RS based project for GAE I've wrote a while ago, and its open. See https://github.com/ipeirotis/ReadabilityMetrics/ for an overview)

Comment: Hmm, I'll try the unpack option if that's the only way to use this appengine-maven-plugin. Do you know if there's some doc to describe the plugins configuration options and what it expects / needs from a distribution to do its work?

Comment: @aldrinleal, are you sure appDir is a valid configuration in appengine-maven-plugin? I don't see it in the [raw source](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/source/browse/src/main/java/com/google/appengine/AbstractAppCfgMojo.java). Note that it is a valid parameter in maven-gae-plugin which is different from appengine-maven-plugin.

Comment: Nice one. I didn't know there was an appengine-maven-plugin. And you're right - AppDir is hardcoded (see http://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/source/browse/src/main/java/com/google/appengine/appcfg/Update.java)

Comment: its new as of 1.7.4 which came out in december